# Eight-sided dice from six-sided dice

Tags: probability, combinations, dice

How do I simulate 8-faced dice with only 6-faced dice?

I have been given the hint that $6^3$ is divisible by 8.

Comment: Hint: Can you simulate 8-faced dice with coins? And can you simulate coins with 6-faced dice?

Comment: is that correct to use binary number?

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean, then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roll the die three times subtracting 1 from each result. Arrange the outcomes as the digits of the base-6 figure $d_0d_1d_2$. Converting this number to decimal you'll have a number between 0 and 215. Assign 1 as the outcome of your 8-faced die when the number is between 0 and 26, 2 when the number is between 27 and 53 and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Using the hint: Think about the number of ways you can roll three $6$-sided dice, and how you might be able to partition them into $8$ different groups of possibilities, each with the same size.

Comment: But how can I think of it exactly? I have tried to think about it but can hardly get the answer.

Comment: Well, Y.X., start at the beginning. How many ways can you roll three 6-sided dice?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think that is 6^3=216.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just do not know how to define the number correspond to each result. Could you please give me a solution please? I have tried but fail to get the solution.

Comment: @Y.X. Here's another hint. How can you make one roll of a 6-sided die like the flip of a coin?

Comment: OK, 216. Now, if you partition those 216 into 8 different groups of the same size, Y.X., how big will each group be?

Comment: I think Y.X. has lost interest in the question.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Thanks so much. I have solved that!

Answer (score 0):

throw the dice, multiply the results together, divide by 27, round the result up to a whole number